# Unable to create a new web application in netbeans- AbstractMethodError

Tags: jsp, web-applications, netbeans-7, web.xml

I am trying to create a new web application in Netbeans.
When I am deploying , I am getting the below exception.
I have not created or added any library. There is just index.jsp saying Hello World.
I am using JDK 1.6 and Tomcat 7.

exception

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

root cause

> java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory.getJspApplicationContext(Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;)Ljavax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext;
>     org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:31)
>     org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:49)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:180)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

As far as web.xml is concerned, its content is

```xml
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

< web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0" >

    < session-config>
        < session-timeout>
            30
        < /session-timeout>
    < /session-config>
< /web-app>
```

I have searched through a lot. Most of the solution to this error is related to .jar in lib folder I don't have any jars added.

Whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractMethodError` is generally thrown at **runtime** when the definition of some class has incompatibly changed since the currently executing method was last compiled.It is also generally caught by the compiler. The **.jar** file containing the class `javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory` is creating this exception. **Check `jsp-api.jar` in your tomcat lib folder and verify the correct one is in the `classpath`**. Ensure that there is no other version of .jar file having the same class is causing this issue.

Comment: Ok. So you are trying to say one version of the class is used in compilation and another for execution ?                                   How to check classpath? Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: Can you explain how you created the web app in the question? What are all present under libraries?

Comment: File->New Project->Java Web->Web Application : Clicked on Next -> entered project name and location -> Server: Apache Tomcat 7 ; Java EE Version:Java EE 6 Web and clicked on finish.                            That's it. I have not added any libraries. Under Libraries folder I can only see JDK1.6 and Apache Tomcat 7 details. Under Apache Tomcat 7 there are few jar files